# openvpn restriction

Tags: openvpn

I've set up an openvpn server at my place and handed out a certificate to a client who has an openvpn client at his place. However, I require that he should be able to connect to the VPN server only from one IP (his current one). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a firewall at the perimeter of your network (or on the vpn server at the very least). My suggestion would be to create a firewall rule that allows vpn connections to the server only from his ip address.